# How can I overwrite the mouse coordinates of a button relative to the entire window?

Tags: python, tkinter

### Background

I am creating a cartesian graph GUI where each node on the graph is a `Frame()` object placed on the `grid()` of my Tkinter object. This is the interface for a pathfinding algorithm.

### Goal

I want to change the color of whatever node is clicked on. This would create an "obstacle."

### Problem

The mouse coordinates are relative to the individual frames within the graph, instead of the entire window.

For example, a node at (9,9) in a 10x10 graph should output pixel coordinates of the location in the window. However, the coordinates are relative to the position inside the node. So the top left is 0,0 when it should be approximately 200,200.

Should I try and map the coordinates to the `grid`? or is that just an object that structures the window? Is there a way to overwrite the mouse position to only the parent window?

#### TLTR

The coordinates of my mouse are relative to the `Frame()` in the `grid` instead of the parent window of the Tkinter object.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Node:
    """ Constructor and other methods """

    def draw(self, x, y):
        if self.nodeType == 'open':
            frame = tk.Frame(
                master=window,
                bg="black",
                borderwidth=1,
                width = 40,
                height = 40
            )
            frame.grid(row=x,column=y)
            label = tk.Label(master = frame, text="     ")
            label.pack()

    """ Other conditions drawing start and end nodes which are identical """

class Graph:
    def __init__(self,master,size,startX,startY,endX,endY):
        """ Miscelaneous constructor stuff for A* Algorithm """

        window.bind("<Button-1>", self.handleMouseClick)

    
    def _eventCoords(self, event):
        row = int(event.y)
        col = int(event.x)
        print(row), 
        print(col)
        return row, col

    def handleMouseClick(self, event):
        print(event.x, event.y)
        row, column = self._eventCoords(event)
        if(self.graph[row][column].nodeType != 'open'):
            return
        self.graph[row][column].nodeType = "closed"
        self.drawObsticle(row, column)
    
    def drawObsticle(self, row, col):
        frame = tk.Frame(
                master=window,
                bg="black",
                borderwidth=1,
                width = 40,
                height = 40
            )
        frame.grid(row=row,column=col)
        label = tk.Label(master = frame, bg = "gray", text="     ")
        label.pack()

    def displayGraph(self):
        """ Trivail 2D for loop """

    def getAdj(self,node):
        """ Path helper function """

    def inRange(self,x,y):
        """ Path helper function """
    
    def findShortestPath(self, event):
        """ Path Algorithm """

size = int(sys.argv[1])
startX = int(sys.argv[2])
startY = int(sys.argv[3])
endX = int(sys.argv[4])
endY = int(sys.argv[5])

window = tk.Tk()
w = Graph(window, size, startX, startY, endX, endY)
window.title('Path Finder')
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calculate back what Frame was clicked based on the coordinates, you can use `event.widget` to get the clicked Frame directly. However, it would be much easier to bind the Button click to the Frame itself, so that each Frame handles it's own click. Here's an example you can run:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Node(tk.Frame):
    BLOCK_COLOR = "black"
    CLEAR_COLOR = "light gray"
    def __init__(self,master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.config(borderwidth=1, bg=self.CLEAR_COLOR, relief=tk.RAISED)
        self.bind('<1>', self.on_click)

    def on_click(self, event=None):
        if self['bg'] == self.CLEAR_COLOR:
            self['bg'] = self.BLOCK_COLOR
        else:
            self['bg'] = self.CLEAR_COLOR

class Graph(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None, rows=5, columns=5, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        for row_num in range(rows):
            for col_num in range(columns):
                f = Node(self)
                f.grid(row=row_num, column=col_num, sticky='nsew')
        self.rowconfigure(list(range(rows)), weight=1, uniform='cell', minsize=40)
        self.columnconfigure(list(range(columns)), weight=1, uniform='cell', minsize=40)

window = tk.Tk()
w = Graph(window)
w.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
window.title('Path Finder')
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. I now have a great reference to draw from... and probably spend a while googling the syntax to understand it, haha.